# Calling method X from each parent

Tags: php, oop, class, reflection

what i'm trying to do is call each method "init" from current class's parents.

I'm doing that to avoid programmers to have to call init method (parent::init()) each time they create an init method in a new controller.

Example:

```
class Aspic\Controller { } // main controller
class ControllerA extends Aspic\Controller { public function init() {/* do something 1 */}  
class ControllerB extends ControllerA {}
class ControllerC extends ControllerB { public function init() { /* do something 2 */ }
class ControllerD extends ControllerC {}
```

As you can see the `init` methods do not call parent `init` method but i want my app (there is an option) do it.

Thus when I'm loading `ControllerD`, before calling it's `init` method (there isn't in the example but the app test it), i want to call each parent `init` method.

sound like this:

```
parent::init(); // Controller C init
parent::parent::parent::init(); // Controller A init
```

So i did :

```
if($this->_autoCallParentsInit) {
    // Aspic\Controller is the main controller, which is the mother of all others
    $aspicControllerRc = new \ReflectionClass('Aspic\\Controller');
    $rc = new \ReflectionClass($this); // We are in D
    $currPrefix = '';

    // Calling each init methods of current class parent
    // Avoid using parent::init() in each controller
    while(($parentClass = $rc->getParentClass()) AND $aspicControllerRc->isInstance($parentClass)) {
        /* 
        $aspicControllerRc->isInstance($parentClass)
        => because Aspic\Controller extends a "Base class". Thus, we stopped at Aspic\Controller
        */

        $currPrefix .= 'parent::';

        // Must have explicit method (not inherited from parent) BUT actually hasMethod does not care
        if($parentClass->hasMethod('init')) {
            call_user_func($currPrefix.'init');                     
        }
    }
}
```

This is not working because `ReflectionClass::isInstance` does not accept others argument than the object we want to test (and the not a `ReflectionClass` object representing it as in the example)

**
Simply:
I have an object $x, and i want to call the `init` method of each parent of the class of $x.
**

Is it possible ?

I hope i was clear :)

Thanks

Comment: Try to improve your formatting!

Comment: That's not easy in the web editor :). That's done

Comment: It looks like you're trying to achieve something with inheritance that you should encapsulate into code of it's own instead because you're not using the right tool for the job. But it's hard to say what you actually want from your question, so I can not make a suggestion on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

ControllerB has an `init()` method by virtue of extending ControllerA, so you shouldn't have to call parent::parent::init() to get to A's from C. You should be fine to call `parent::init()` from ControllerD, which will call ControllerC's `init()` method. If ControllerC calls `parent::init()` it will be calling ControllerA's `init()` method.

If you're trying to skip the Controller's specific `init()` code when being called by a subclass, you could add a flag `function init($call_parent = false)` and then, from lower controllers, call `parent::init(true);`

Comment: Yes but that's the probem : i don't want to call parent::init(); in lower controller

Comment: If you don't want to call the parent::init() in ControllerD (for example), just have an `init()` method that doesn't call `parent::init()`. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding. If so, maybe clarify exactly which `init()`s should be called from ControllerD.

Comment: parent::init() should be called implicitely from each init function. I try to call each init method (if defined by the class) on each parent of an object.

Comment: Might be misunderstanding still, but does `class ControllerY extends ContollerX { function init() { parent::init(); //controller specific code next } }` not work when you use it for any Controller that needs to do something specific in its `init()` call?

Comment: ok, yes sure that works, i think it is not possible to do what i want, i will look for another solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the classes statically (which, from your code not stating `static function`, I assume you're not), have you tried using the `__construct()` method? It gets automatically called when you instantiate the class, for example:

```
class MyClass {
  public function __construct() {
    echo 'Hello!';
  }
}

$class = new MyClass();
```

That will automatically output 'Hello!', however if you extend the class and that child class contains a `__construct()` method you will have to put `parent::__construct()` inside the childs construct method, however you wont have to do it for every parent, just the once, for example:

```
class MyClassB extends MyClass {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    echo 'World!';
  }
}

class MyOtherClass extends MyClassB
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    echo 'How\'s it going!';
  }
}

$class = new MyOtherClass();
```

That will output "Hello! World! How's it going!"

Comment: That's the same, i made an init function (called by the controller) to avoid calling parent::__construct BUT the problem come again when there is more than one child from Main controller (aspic): The first child of main controller redefine init method (so it don't have to call any parent method), but if first child of mainController has a child too, it can not define init function because it will rewrite "first child of mainController init"

Comment: I don't see the problem with having to put at least one line in each `__construct()` or `init` method to call the parent, why go through the trouble of trying to automatically do it when one line is just fine, a lot of people call the parents `__construct` method inside the child classes, what ypuit seems illogical.

Comment: @Leto: You should first think about your design of composition *before* starting to code. It's really hard to understand what you try to achieve with your design.